# Liferay 7 + MySql 5.5.44 not support

Tags: mysql, liferay, tomcat8, liferay-7

I downloaded Liferay 7 (liferay-portal-7.0-ce-ga1) on ubuntu 14.04 when I try to connect with MySql DB, that :then I found an error inthat: Liferay7 does not support lesser then **MySQL 5.6.4**. But I've already installed **MySql 5.5.44** on an environment. 
On an earlier version of MySql i.e. 5.5.44 other portals running perfectly.

here is the LOGS,

```
01:43:13,809 INFO  [elasticsearch[Jade Dragon][clusterService#updateTask][T#1]][metadata:317] [Jade Dragon] [liferay-0] update_mapping [LiferayDocumentType]

    __    ____________________  _____  __
   / /   /  _/ ____/ ____/ __ \/   \ \/ /
  / /    / // /_  / __/ / /_/ / /| |\  /
 / /____/ // __/ / /___/ _, _/ ___ |/ /
/_____/___/_/   /_____/_/ |_/_/  |_/_/

Starting Liferay Portal Community Edition 7.0.0 CE GA1 (Wilberforce / Build 7000 / March 31, 2016)

01:43:18,624 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][StartupAction:110] There are no patches installed
01:43:18,760 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][StartupAction:169] Please upgrade to at least MySQL 5.6.4. The portal no longer supports older versions of MySQL.
```

I've queries:

- Is there any fix available for that except upgrading entire MySql?
- Why Liferay 7 not supporting earlier versions of MySql, Reason behind that?

Answer (score 1):

Why?

New releases of software typically use newer dependencies. It's quite some work to support older software, thus one is typically happy to just support the latest version (and you'd want the latest version supported, right?)

Liferay 7 also now requires Java8, something that came in during the last days of the beta cycle - because now every application server that it's running on does support Java8. If that wouldn't happen, you'd be tied to the past forever.

Is there another option?

I assume that you'd be able to implement an adapter to older MySql versions yourself (and contribute it to the community) - I'm aware that there's someone currently implementing CE support for Oracle and SQL Server (these will be supported by the commercial offering only)